# Potentially redundant: construction / lutherie

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think most of the times, these two terms are redundant in music.SE.

Perhaps one could make one the synonym of the other.

Your opinion?

EDIT: I mean, I see many questions on guitar construction, tagged construction,  also tagged lutherie. I see this as redundant in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

No, lutherie is string instruments only. They are therefore not synonyms. Possibly lutherie could be seen as too specific, but I don't see why.

Comment: In several languages, lutherie is applied to wind instrument as well.

Comment: @ogerard: Well, not in English. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lutherie

Comment: @Lennart : I know that, it was not exactly my point. Please see my question edit.

Comment: @ogerard: Right, nobody is going to ask questions about lutherie in general that is about both guitars, lutes and cellos. So in fact you are saying that it is too *general* and will always be qualified with "guitar" as well. In which case "construction" would work as well as "lutherie". I think it will be confusing to make them synonyms, but I see your point.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point about `[guitar][construction]` being the same as `[lutherie]`. The problem is, as Lennart says, that lutherie isn't a real synonym of construction. And we can't just remove it, since the Guitars people use "lutherie" so often.

Comment: @Matthew: So although making them synonyms might be confusing, *not* making them synonyms might be even more confusing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that we want people interested in general instrument construction to see questions tagged [lutherie](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lutherie) when they look at [construction](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction).

The only way that's possible is for questions tagged "lutherie" to also be tagged "construction".

On the other hand, questions tagged "electric-guitar" don't need to be tagged "guitar" as well.  A search for [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) will show [electric-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-guitar) as well, since "guitar" is a substring of "electric-guitar".

Summary: Duplication is not necessary for some tags, but it is unfortunately necessary here.

Comment: Unless we want to rename `lutherie` to `lutherie-construction`, but I don't think we do.